# perl get all URL parameters at once

Tags: perl, apache

I am using following perl code for parsing incoming URL GET data:

```
use Apache2::Request;
use Apache2::RequestRec;

$req = Apache2::Request->new($r);
$pg = $req->param('pg');
$ord = $req->param('order');
```

And I have following URL:
dom.com/index.pl?pg=1&order=desc&color=red&number=15

Question: How can I get "pg=1&order=desc&color=red&number=15" part of URL at once? like:

```
$allparams= $req->param;
```

Answer (score 1):

> With mod_perl2, the environment object $r must be an [Apache2::RequestRec](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Apache2%3a%3aRequestRec) object. In that case, all methods from Apache2::RequestRec are inherited.

So,

```
$req->args
```